# simple PHP contact form not sending one input form value

Tags: php, html, forms, post, contact-form

As the title says, I have a simple PHP contact form that one of the input values is not being POST with the rest of the values.

It is a part of a div that is hidden by jquery until another value is clicked, another value that is a part of the same div that does POST, so unsure if that is causing a problem.

The attending and song_choice are the inputs that are hidden by jquery until accepts radio button is clicked. The attending input is the one input that does not POST. I am unsure what the issue may be, must be something simple that I am missing but from my googling, I cannot figure it out.
Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="email_form.php" method="POST">
    <h5 class="rsvp-text">Please Respond by <strong>August 15, 2015</strong></h5>
    <input class="rsvp-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please Enter Your First & Last Name:" ><br>
    <input type="radio" class="rsvp-radio" id="accepts-button"  value="Accepts with Pleasure" name="rsvp_response"> Accepts with Pleasure
    <input type="radio" class="rsvp-radio" id="declines-button" value="Declines with Regret" name="rsvp_response"> Declines with Regret<br>
        <div id="accepts-qs">
            Number Attending:
            <input name="attending" type="text" placeholder="Enter a number:"><br>
            <p><em>"While we love to see the children run & play,</br> this is an adults only kind of day."</em></p>
            You Promise to Dance if We Play:<br>
            <textarea class="rsvp-input" type="text" name="song_choice" placeholder="Song Title and Artist:"></textarea></br>
        </div>
    <input class="rsvp-button" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
/* e-mail recipient & subject */
$myemail = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Wedding RSVP";

/* rsvp responses */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$rsvp_response = $_POST['rsvp_response'];
$attending = $_POST['$attending'];
$song_choice = $_POST['song_choice'];

/* email message*/
$message = "From: $name\nResponse: $rsvp_response\nNumber Attending: $attending\nSong Choice: $song_choice";

/* mail function to send email */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor back to home page */
header('Location: index.html');
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$_POST['$attending'];` be `$_POST['attending'];`?

Answer (score 3):

Change `$_POST['$attending']` to `$_POST['attending']` and I believe it should work.

Comment: WOW. I feel really dumb. I guess, I just needed fresh eyes on it. Thanks

Comment: @bs_in_tx Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$attending = $_POST['$attending'];
```

for

```
$attending = $_POST['attending'];
```